# How to modify elements in collection that match predicate upon copying?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to copy a list and modify items while copying if they match specific criteria. Is there a better/faster/more idiomatic way of achieving this?

```scala
class Animal(val t: String, val n : String) {}

val farm =  List[Animal](
  new Animal("pig","squeeky"),
  new Animal("chicken","clucker"),
  new Animal("fox","grr"),
  new Animal("chicken","clucky"),
  new Animal("chicken","cluckster"))

// i want to replace 'fox' with 'deadfox'
val safefarm = farm.map(n => {
  if (n.t == "fox")
    new Animal("deadfox","")
  else n
})

farm.map(_.t)
// res4: List[String] = List(pig, chicken, fox, chicken, chicken)

safefarm.map(_.t)
// res5: List[String] = List(pig, chicken, deadfox, chicken, chicken)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make this more elegant by making `Animal` a case class and using pattern matching in your `map`.

```
case class Animal(t: String, n : String)

val farm =  List[Animal](
  Animal("pig","squeeky"),
  Animal("chicken","clucker"),
  Animal("fox","grr"),
  Animal("chicken","clucky"),
  Animal("chicken","cluckster")
)

val safefarm = farm map {
  case Animal("fox", _) => Animal("deadfox", "")
  case a => a
}
```

`map` only makes one pass through the `List`, so this is as fast as it gets. But I think the pattern matching makes it much more readable.

Comment: Thanks. If I were to wnt to copy the "n" field from the original, to the new and just change the "t", how would I do it? In other words, I want the replaced item to be n=deadfox, t=the original item's t. Something like case Animal("fox", _) => Animal("deadfox", _) -- which is wrong.

Comment: The underscore means you don't care what the value is. You can match it with another symbol though. `case Animal("fox", n) => Animal("deadfox", n)`

Answer (score 1):

More of a side note, for a given `case class`, the `copy` method creates a new `case class` instance with selected fields changed; consider this example:

```
scala> case class Animal(t: String, n : String)
defined class Animal

scala> val a = Animal("fox","grr")
a: Animal = Animal(fox,grr)

scala> val b = a.copy(t="deadfox")
b: Animal = Animal(deadfox,grr)
```

Here `b: Animal` is a *copy* of `a: Animal` with field `t: String` changed.